# Upload many images django rest framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, file-upload, django-rest-framework

I try to upload many images to one post.

[image: models.py]
[image: serializers.py]
[image: serializers.py]

I try to achive this:
[image: I try to achive this:]

When I post data i get this:
[image]

What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: I think you're doing something wrong when uploading the image because that error only show up when you don't put an image in the uploading form and hit the submit button

Comment: I put image in uploading form and still get this response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have write the code for you. Try this:

```
class PostCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField()
    content = serializers.CharField()
    price = serializers.CharField()
    duration = serializers.CharField()
    destination = serializers.CharField()
    images = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.ImageField())
    _id = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post 
        fields = [
            'title',
            'content',
            'price',
            'duration',
            'destination',
            'images'
        ]

    def create(self,validated_data):
        title        = validated_data['title']
        content    = validated_data['content']
        price        = validated_data['price']
        duration        = validated_data['duration'] 
        destination   = validated_data['destination'] 
        images   = validated_data['images'] 
        _id   = validated_data['_id'] 

        post_obj = Post.objects.create(
            title=title,
            content = content,
            price=price,
            duration=duration,
            destination=destination,
            ) 

        _id = Post.objects.get(id=_id)
        if not _id.exists():
            raise ValidationError('id does not exists')

        PostImage.objects.bulk_create([PostImage(post=_id,image=i) for i in images])
    
        return validated_data
```

Comment: After few changes it works! Thank you very much. I've posted finally code below, maybe it helps for someone.

Answer (score 0):

It is solution for my problem.

[image]

[image]